# addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not execute the code inside onDataChange()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am just trying to do a simple program (in Android Studio). I have used addListenerForSingleValueEvent(). But the code inside onDataChange() does not execute at all.

```
dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d("TAG", "message");
    }
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.toString());
    }
});
```

Nothing is displayed in Log.

Comment: Step one is to stop ignoring potential errors:
`public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }` Is there something printed out in the console?

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this right now.

Comment: I have put another log inside onCancelled(), but that is also not executed.

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on user device?

Comment: 100%. The device successfully signs in the firebase database.

Comment: But neither OnDataChange() is trigerred nor onCancelled().

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the updated code. If neither `onDataChange` nor `onCancelled` gets called, you might want to [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output for hints on what's goign on.